# The rise of BCI

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, biology, perception

If EEG and MEG are measuring different aspects of neural oscillations, why can't we measure the combined signals as a whole, when we are doing the same for higher frequencies?

Why did the us navy require 25+miles of antenna to replicate a frequency range our brains are producing in the space of a few cm?

If EEG and MEG are touted by many as one way to read minds,what about the bit rate problem associated with ELF?

What are your thoughts on neural privacy and the associated shielding techniques that might need to come of age for the above stated revolution?

Looking forward,

Links.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Sanguine

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnins.2016.00429/full

https://lsspjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s40504-017-0050-1

https://theconversation.com/helping-or-hacking-engineers-and-ethicists-must-work-together-on-brain-computer-interface-technology-77759

Comment: This probably belongs at psychology.stackexchange.com which also encompasses neuroscience.

Comment: On Stack Exchange sites, a question post should consist of a single question, or at least a small number of closely related questions that can be answered as a unit.

Comment: Okay...my assumption was that it was a closely related set of questions , it started with brain waves and why we areeasuring it separately , yet unable to measure it as a whole , then compared it to an expirement where they did it , but required an antenna that was an oddity (maybe power) , when compared to the human brain and the problems they faced it , especially with regards to data rate that make BCI a problem using the above technique , the final question was a bit of base , because of the shielding and a general idea on nuero privacy

Comment: @PM2Ring: Thanks...I will post it as separate questions